# How do JS function object store in memory?

Tags: javascript

It is said that 'almost everything is an object', including functions.
So, what exactly happened in memory when I do something like:

```
function func(){
    // do something
}
var f = func;
f()
```

In my opinion, it first create an object instance for 'function func', then it cloned(deep copy, I guess) 'function func' and assigned it to the container 'var f'.
Is that right?
Or, how does it work?
Thanks!

Comment: It isn't cloned, its the same function with a new label f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my opinion, it first create an object instance for 'function func'

Yes, that was when it processed the `function func() { }` part

> , then it cloned(deep copy, I guess) 'function func' and assigned it to the container 'var f'.

No, not at all. What's stored in `f` is a value called an "object reference" (or frequently just "reference"). Think of it as a number that the JavaScript engine can use to find the object elsewhere in memory. (We cannot see the actual value, but we don't ever need to.)

So when all of your code has run, and before any garbage collection is done, you have this in memory *(leaving out some unnecessary detail)*:

```
func:Ref89895−−−+
                |
                |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                +−−−−−>| function           |
                |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                |      | name: "func"       |
f:Ref89895−−−−−−+      | length: 0          |
                       | ...                |
                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

There's `func`, which is the automatic binding *(waves hands, basically a variable)* created by `function func() { }` in the current context, and `f`, the variable you've assigned a copy of its value to (shown as Ref89895, but again, we never actually see these values).

Comment: But Javascript is not a single thread language, what if before the 'function func' return and another thread also called func() ? How can a single function object run in two place? Or, is that another topic?

Comment: @HubertLin: Threading is largely irrelevant to the above, but there's no reason the same function can't run simultaneously in more than one thread. But note that there aren't many JavaScript hosts that have multiple threads that run in the same environment (e.g., have access to the same variables and functions); browsers don't (the main UI thread and all web workers run in environments isolated from each other) and NodeJS is single-threaded. Rhino and Nashorn are the only significant JS engines I know of that have shared-environment multi-threading (because they run on the Java VM).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I used to think all threads in browser shared same environment.   Knowing that threads are isolated in browser solved a lot of my problems! Thanks again!